# Partial fraction decomposition of p'/p

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the partial fraction decomposition of $p'/p$ if p is a nonconstant polynomial and $p(z)=c\prod_{j=1}^{k}{(z-z_{j})^{m_{j}}}$?

Comment: What have you tried? The case where all the roots are distinct is a very simple application of the product rule.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$p'(z)=c\sum_{j=1}^km_j(z-z_j)^{m_j-1}\prod_{i\neq j}(z-z_i)^{m_i}$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the complex logarithm and its main branch:

$$\frac{p'}p=\left(\log p\right)'=\left(\log \left(c\prod_{j=1}^k(z-z_j)^{m_j}\right)\right)'=\left(\log c+\sum_{j=1}^km_j\log(z-z_j)\right)'=$$

$$=\sum_{j=1}^k\frac{m_j}{z-z_j}$$

Comment: +1, I really like this method (although it should be $m_{j}$ in the numerator, not $j$)

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Confusion over the exponents. Corrected, thanks.

Comment: If you're using the "main" (principal?) branch, strictly speaking your equality is only valid on the set of $z$ where $p(z)$ is not negative real. (The argument can be saved though with a litte extra work.) Your use of "rules for logarithms" also have to be justified.

Comment: Yes, the main branch erases the non-positive reals. If there is some negative value there then you can choose any other half-ray containing zero, say the non-negative imaginary axis or whatever. About the justification: I bet somebody could be forced to do it...not I, of course. As long as we keep the argument of the guys in $\;(-\pi,\pi)\;$ all's dandy. If someone wants to go out of this (and still without some branch cut), then some fitting multiple of $\;2\pi\;$ must be added to the argument for the "identities" to be true.

Answer (score 0):

It is $$ \sum_{j=1}^k \frac{m_j}{z-z_j} $$ as you can check multiplying by $p(z)$

Comment: That $\;c\;$ shouldn't be there...

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
{{\rm p}'\pars{z} \over {\rm p}\pars{z}}&=\totald{\ln\pars{{\rm p}\pars{z}}}{z}
=\sum_{j = 1}^{k}{m_{j} \over z - z_{j}}
\end{align}